# ColdFusion 10, IIS 7.5, and custom 404 page

Tags: coldfusion, iis-7.5, coldfusion-10

I am attempting to setup a custom 404 error with CF10 and IIS 7.5. Previous to CF10 (and IIS 7), you can get the URL of the non-existent page via the querystring (e.g., 404;http://www.example.com/some/file.html) when the custom 404 page is processed. However, with CF10 and IIS 7.5, the querystring returns 404;http://www.example.com/jakarta/isapi_redirect.dll. Is there a way to retrieve the actual URL of the missing path, like in prior versions?

Comment: Do you have the missing template option configured in the CF admin? If you're using a centralized workflow page (ex index.cfm) you can log the request/workflow easily enough in most cases.

Comment: No, I don't have the missing template option configured. I wanted to avoid using a server wide 404, since I only need the custom 404 for one of the sites running on the server.

Comment: Have you tried the app.cfc onMissingTemplate() method to get the page? The downside to this method (at least used to be, I haven't re-visited it in awhile) if a directory request will not trip it.

Ben Nadel has a good post on it: http://bit.ly/13E6Rxq

Comment: I should have noted this in my question. I'm working with a legacy app that's still using Application.cfm. Converting to Application.cfc is not feasible at the moment.

Comment: @RHPT - Did you ever figure this out? The question has come up again -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694932/coldfusion-10-iis-non-existant-urls-that-are-cfm-files-retrieving-original-u

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that I posted to the page Miguel-F commented on:

[ColdFusion 10 + IIS: Non-existant URLs that are CFM files. Retrieving original URL after executing 404 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18694932/coldfusion-10-iis-non-existant-urls-that-are-cfm-files-retrieving-original-u)

It's not pretty but it works...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Both this question and the one I linked to are pretty much the same.  You would want to mark this one or the other one as a duplicate right?  I don't have enough rep to do that.  I'm new at this, sorry...  Let me know what I can do to make this work right.

Answer (score -1):

Problems with custom 404 error pages and IIS 7.5 were addressed in the latest CF10 update - Update 11. You have to re-run the web server connector once you install the update. If you do not re-run the web server connector, then the IIS/custom 404 error pages problem will not be fixed. [This is the official blog post](http://blogs.coldfusion.com/post.cfm/coldfusion-10-does-the-connector-need-to-be-re-installed-for-update-11) regarding Update 11 and the web server connector. The fixes introduced in Update 11 may solve your problem.

Comment: I am familiar with the issue you mention, but that's not the problem I have. I can get the custom 404 to display correctly. I just can't get the path of the missing template to appear on the 404